# How can we restart Jenkins service with hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins was not able to execute basic windows batch command so, we had to restart jenkins through the UI. After restarting Jenkins, it gave an error that it cant read the config.xml file, so we changed the xml version from 1.1 to 1.0, but still Jenkins is not getting restarted. How should we proceed further now?

```
> ***hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException:
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> jenkins.model.Jenkins.get()Ljenkins/model/Jenkins;    at
> hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:237) Caused by:
> org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException:
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> jenkins.model.Jenkins.get()Ljenkins/model/Jenkins;    at
> org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)    at
> jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)  at
> jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1020)   at
> jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:864)    at
> hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)    at
> hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)    at
> hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:225) Caused by:
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> jenkins.model.Jenkins.get()Ljenkins/model/Jenkins;    at
> hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.ComputerHistoryListener.onConfigurationChange(ComputerHistoryListener.java:52)
>   at
> hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.updateComputerList(AbstractCIBase.java:209)
>   at jenkins.model.Jenkins.updateComputerList(Jenkins.java:1349)  at
> jenkins.model.Nodes$7.run(Nodes.java:304)     at
> hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1312)     at
> hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1189)  at
> jenkins.model.Nodes.load(Nodes.java:295)  at
> jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.run(Jenkins.java:2798)   at
> org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
>   at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)   at
> jenkins.model.Jenkins$8.runTask(Jenkins.java:1009)    at
> org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)  at
> org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a possibility of some syntax error in `config.xml` file.
You can generate the `config.xml` file by removing/moving the earlier config file to some other location.
Steps:

1. Stop Jenkins service `service jenkins stop`
2. Remove the `config.xml` file present in your `JENKINS_HOME` location to some other location just for backup.
3. Start jenkins service `service jenkins start`
   Once you start jenkins again, `config.xml` will be created and jenkins should start.
   **Edit**:
   If this also does not works then there could be some plugins which could also cause the issue. You can give a try by taking backup of your plugins folder then deleting it and then doing a restart of jenkins service and browser

Comment: Two comments :1.  I would rename, not remove the old file. 2. Also check the diskspace on the machine.

Comment: Thank you Altaf, tried the above solution but after restart it is still giving the same error.

Comment: Tried renaming as well.

Comment: @Annie : May be there could be some plugins which could also cause the issue. You can give a try by taking backup of your plugins folder then deleting it and then doing a restart of jenkins service and browser

Comment: I wanted to avoid that step of deleting plugin folder, but looks like there is no other alternative.

Comment: @Annie , yes you can take a backup of that folder as unfortunately  restart is not working for you

Comment: Thank you, removing the plugin worked, but lost all the configured job, its like a clean slate.